# `crontab -e` sometimes fails with "Creation of temporary crontab file failed"

Tags: ubuntu, files, cron, io, storage

*From time to time* `crontab -e` fails on me on a Ubuntu box. It is the same for all users including the root and `crontab -eu <user>` under the root. Goes like this on a regular basis, a success here and there:

```
$ crontab -e
/tmp/crontab.SHw8Ge: Input/output error
Creation of temporary crontab file failed - aborting

$ crontab -e
/tmp/crontab.L8gEG4: Input/output error
Creation of temporary crontab file failed - aborting

$ crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab

$ crontab -e
/tmp/crontab.Vvp59T: Input/output error
Creation of temporary crontab file failed - aborting

$ crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
```

I don't seem to be having problems creating files there by hand or script repeatedly:

```
$ vim /tmp/crontab.Vvp59T
$ ls -la /tmp/crontab.Vvp59T
-rw-r--r-- 1 <user> <user> 6 2014-07-01 04:17 /tmp/crontab.Vvp59T
```

`/tmp` permissions:

```
$ ls -la /
...
drwxrwxrwt  92 root root 20480 2014-07-01 04:24 tmp
...
```

Looks like a storage issue to me, no clue how to prove or rule that out. Any ideas what could be causing this and how to test?

```
$ lsb_release -dc
Description:    Ubuntu 9.10
Codename:       karmic
```

**Update regarding comments:**

`/tmp` disk space use is 5%, inode use 1%. Crontab file size is 13K, ~200 lines. All this seems okay.

Comment: You could run `strace crontab -e` in order to get a more precise error message. Are these crontab files big? Is `/tmp` nearly full or runs out of inodes? Maybe not creating the file is the problem but writing "much" data to it.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thanks for the hints. Added the info to the question. I'll add `strace` results later, need to get more familiar with it, never used it before.

Comment: check if /tmp is mounted in proper way, make sure it is not read only

Comment: @HaukeLaging In the strace output check the open/write/read system calls return value, read their man page to know the meaning.

Comment: @Emmanuel And that was a message to me...?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Sorry of course not :)

Comment: You'll probably want to make some backups to be safe.

Use smartmontools to start monitoring and gathering data on possible disk problems.  Do a full disk test: smartctl -t long /dev/sda

After it's done take a look smartctl -a /dev/sda and watch numbers in attributes 5, 196, 197, and 198.  If you have errors, you'll have to do a fsck with read/write test to get the drive to mark those as bad.  If your disk is bad enough you'll have to replace the disk.

Comment: If it's a disk issue, it could also be an issue with the cron or your editor binaries, so I would do a reinstall of those packages after you have fixed any disk issues.

Comment: For me, it was because of misconfigured quotatool... Running `quotaoff -a` solved the problem (and later on properly configuring it again)...